# Error System.ObjectDisposedException VSTO SmartTag?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, vsto

I'm having trouble getting a vsto project to work.  It's a simple Word 2007 addin application that adds a smarttag identifier.

here's the error:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.SmartTagCollection.BeginInit()
   at WordInWord.ThisAddIn.BeginInitialization() in C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\WordInWord\WordInWord\ThisAddIn.Designer.cs:line 129
   at WordInWord.ThisAddIn.InitializeDataBindings() in C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\WordInWord\WordInWord\ThisAddIn.Designer.cs:line 66
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.EntryPointComponentBase.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.IEntryPoint.InitializeDataBindings()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.AddInAdapter.ExecutePhase(ExecutionPhases executionPhases)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Internal.OfficeAddInAdapter.InitializeEntryPointsHelper()
```

somehow the smarttags are disposed?  I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I knew this applicatio worked before so I published it.  When I went to install the add in the install app required the VSTO 3.0 runtime SP1 update.  The app requires the SP1 update.